# Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC - Installed updates differ between Windows Update and Installed Updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows Update - **View Update History** and **Installed Updates** show different things:

[image]

Kiosks running Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 1809 - 17763.2061.

I'd assumed these should list the same things, but they don't. Would I be right in thinking that Installed Updates should be correct one?

What's the more appropriate way (nicely date ordered) to do this on the command line or in Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your update history is showing some failed updates, whereas your control panel on the right is showing only updates that have actually installed.
You could try get-hotfix to show any installed updates on your kiosk.